# Odd behavior from RLIKE and LIKE in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-like

I'm writing some stored procedures to automate regularly used queries on the database, however I am receiving what seems to me to be very odd behavior.

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE SelectOrders(IN item VARCHAR(30), IN category VARCHAR(30))
 BEGIN
     SELECT 
         Order_ID,
         Category,
         Item,
         Discount
     FROM 
         Orders 
     WHERE 
         Item RLIKE item 
         AND Category LIKE category
```

If I call my stored procedure (`CALL SelectOrders('.*', '%');`) in order to return all matches (i.e. by using the wildcards for `RLIKE` and `LIKE`), it will return results, however instead of the expected result, the columns where `RLIKE` or `LIKE` was used (so, Item and Category, in this example) will show `.*` or `%`, respectively.

So an `Orders` table containing -

```
 Order_ID   ||   Category   ||  Item   ||  Discount 
 --------------------------------------------------
      1     ||   Clothing   ||  Hat    ||   0 
      2     ||   Books      ||  Bible  ||   0
```

would return -

```
 Order_ID   ||   Category   ||  Item   ||  Discount 
 --------------------------------------------------
      1     ||      %       ||   .*    ||   0 
      2     ||      %       ||   .*    ||   0
```

If I change the values of the parameters I am passing in (for example, `.*at` for the `item` parameter), it will return the relevant rows from the table (so, in this case, Order_ID 1) but it will still show the `IN` parameter rather than the returned result.

I am not sure what is going on here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Never name a variable or a parameter like a column or something else you use. Yes, even when you think it's case sensitive. Sometimes it's not.

Comment: Gaaaaaaah. Thank you. That was my first thought actually, so I added some backticks, but I didn't think to change the name as well when the backticks had no effect. D'oh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your parameters so they are distinct from column names.  Try this:

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE SelectOrders(IN v_item VARCHAR(30), IN v_category VARCHAR(30))
 BEGIN
     SELECT Order_ID, Category, Item, Discount
     FROM Orders 
     WHERE Item RLIKE v_item AND Category LIKE v_category
```

The use of backticks has no effect on how the value is interpreted.  When you say `Item RLIKE item`, the alias `item` is resolved to the column in the table.  Both times.  You need to name the variables differently to distinguish between the two.